# Azure AD B2C: error for on-premise ad fs as SAML identity provider

Tags: aad-b2c

I was trying to add our on-prem AD FS as SMAL identity provider in azure ad b2c. I followed this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and finished all steps.

Then I tried the Run now endpoint (from aad b2c custom policy), and clicked the new IDP button (MY AD FS), I got the error:
**AADB2C: Unable to connect to the metadata endpoint 'https://MY.ADFS.COM/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml'**

[image: error]

Some notes:

- I run the test from the AD FS Server machine
- I can access the metadata directly from URL https://MY.ADFS.COM/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml in browser (on the AD FS Server machine)

Not sure what I'm missing. Does it matter the AD FS server is corpnet wide only? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from Microsoft. To resolve this error, just put the metadata file on a public storage so that B2C can access it.